# Has Django version 3 stoped the need to register new apps in settings.py installed apps list?

Tags: django

The apps i create are working with out any need for them to be registered in settings.py of the project.

The official documentation also doesn't register its polls app in INSTALLED_APPS.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

What is the use of registering apps in INSTALLED_APPS of settings.py if it works with out registering?

Comment: Is the AppConfig for your apps working? I highly doubt it...   
You can import and use code without registering it as an app, but you won't be able to access it from Django's app registry

Comment: how can i check if i can access it from Django's app registry

Comment: The official documentation also doesn't register the polls app in INSTALLED_APPS 
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: from django.apps import apps                       
apps.is_installed("my_app")

Comment: It Returns False, as expected, since i have not installed it in installed_apps.  why is the routing working then when i try to access  the app. and what is the use of registering it in installed apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, anything you import is known to the code where it is imported, but the inverse is not possible...

Imagine I have two files

```
# a.py

def foo():
    ...

# b.py
from a import foo

def bar():
    foo()
```

In b.py I know about `foo`, but a.py doesn't know about `bar` or even that b.py exists.

Now when you have a router, you import your views which import models, etc. Your full app can work with this. But for Django to know about your app it needs at least some reference to it. The `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings tells Django which apps are meant to be part of your entire Django project. By default, it includes some Django apps. Not every project needs all of them so some (or all) might be removed. Similarly, other 3rd party apps might be added.

Running Django management commands such as `migrate` or `collectstatic` will only work on apps included in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

P.S: Never access `INSTALLED_APPS` in your code, but rather use the app registry via `from django.apps import apps`